# Error while creating data pipeline - security group does not exist

Tags: amazon-data-pipeline

While creating a data pipeline to copy from RDS to S3, I am specifying security group id which refers to a vpc.

It errors out "Service: AmazonEC2; Status Code: 400; Error Code: InvalidGroup.NotFound; "

Comment: Can you post the configuration that you are using for your EC2 resource?

Comment: {
      "instanceType": "#{myEC2InstanceType}",
      "name": "Ec2Instance",
      "actionOnTaskFailure": "terminate",
      "securityGroups": "#{myEc2RdsSecurityGrps}",
      "id": "Ec2Instance",
      "type": "Ec2Resource",
      "terminateAfter": "2 Hours"
    }

"values": {
    "myEC2InstanceType": "t1.micro",
    "myEc2RdsSecurityGrps": "sg-xxxxxx"
  }

Answer (score 0):

The `Ec2Resource` needs to include the `subnetId` of the target subnet in your VPC as well as the security groups. Example from the docs:

```
{
  "id" : "MyEC2Resource",
  "type" : "Ec2Resource",
  "actionOnTaskFailure" : "terminate",
  "actionOnResourceFailure" : "retryAll",
  "maximumRetries" : "1",
  "instanceType" : "m1.medium",
  "securityGroupIds" : [
    "sg-12345678",
    "sg-12345678"
  ],
  "subnetId": "subnet-12345678",
  "associatePublicIpAddress": "true",
  "keyPair" : "my-key-pair"
}
```

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/datapipeline/latest/DeveloperGuide/dp-object-ec2resource.html

Comment: I'm still getting the same error in spite of including the subnet:
{
      "subnetId": "subnet-00a0be7d01a555ebe",
      "securityGroupIds": "sg-033dd38a59c7cb7d0",
      "instanceType": "#{myEC2InstanceType}",
      "name": "Ec2Instance",
      "actionOnTaskFailure": "terminate",
      "id": "Ec2Instance",
      "type": "Ec2Resource",
      "terminateAfter": "2 Hours"
    }

Comment: Just to add: I removed the security group, keeping the subnet id. The Pipeline fails and is cancelled.
Error Message:Unable to create resource for @Ec2Instance_2020-06-15T11:37:31 due to: The subnet ID 'subnet-00a0be7d01a555ebe' does not exist (Service: AmazonEC2; Status Code: 400; Error Code: InvalidSubnetID.NotFound; Request ID: b017ae63-3abf-4289-8bfe-3896fe375977)